# Comportamento diferente dentro e fora da função

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde!

Por exemplo, fiz um script pra redirecionar todas as pessoas do meu site pra Home do site, por conta que, iremos trocar de sistema e com isso, as vendas tem que parar pra podermos conseguir fazer isso.

Fiz uma mini função só pra teste e pra ficar mais organizado. (não tinha necessidade de criar função)

Porém, quando testei, ela redireciona a pessoa pra Home do site, que é a raiz no caso (/) mas ele na raiz também fica redirecionando e forma um loop infinito, ja que está na url que de fato é pra ser redirecionado, (somente com a função)

```
let newRedirect = function(){
    if(window.location.href != "https://www.meusite.com.br/"){
        window.location.href = "https://www.meusite.com.br/";
    }
}
newRedirect();
```

Agora, se eu usar assim (sem função):

```
if(window.location.href != "https://www.meusite.com.br/"){
    window.location.href = "https://www.meusite.com.br/";
}
```

Funciona normalmente e redireciona só uma vez.

Resumindo, por que que com função, mesmo na raiz, fica redirecionando e sem função, não?

Comment: O `location.pathname` retorna só o path, dai você consegue validar com um `!= "/"`.

Comment: Isso não deveria acontecer. Coloque um `alert(window.location.href)` no início da função e veja o que mostra.

Comment: Você pode tentar utilizar também um console.log(window.location.href) assim fica mais fácil de rastrear e entender o que esta acontecendo, qual o valor dê window.location.href...

Comment: Você está utilizando node.js? E o módulo http-server?

Comment: De repente é um problema com hoisting?

Comment: pode ser que seu location.href esteja retornando h ttps://meusite.com.br/ sem o www

Answer (score -1):

Algumas definiçoes da window tem um delay, por isso funciona somente com a funçao que é chamada após a leitura do script, tente utilizar após o document.DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score -3):

A resposta do PaulaoDev pode ja te esclarecer algo. Mas caso vc ainda esteja com problema, o que recomendo é fazer o que o Sam e o Raphael Godoi indicaram.
Comente a linha `window.location.href = "https://www.meusite.com.br/";` e coloque no lugar um `console.log(windows.location.href)` para obter mais informações do que esta acontecendo.